# Integrating Zurb-Foundation's Interchange into a Rails 5 website

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm building my first website using Rails 5 and Zurb's Foundation framework and for the last 2 days I keep hitting a roadblock when I'm trying to integrate Foundation's Interchange plugin in a Rails view, and **I can't seem to get the images to load. All I get in the image's place is the content of the `alt:` attribute.**  Also, I'm using Heroku to host my website.

Up to now I've done the following:

- I've defined my own media queries to use with interchange and added them as properties to `Foundation.Interchange.SPECIAL_QUERIES` as follows:

```js
Foundation.Interchange.SPECIAL_QUERIES['smallretina'] = 'only screen and (min-width: 1px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-width: 1px) and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-width: 1px) and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), only screen and (min-width: 1px) and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-width: 1px) and (min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and (min-width: 1px) and (min-resolution: 2dppx)';
Foundation.Interchange.SPECIAL_QUERIES['mediumretina'] = 'only screen and (min-width: 641px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-width: 641px) and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-width: 641px) and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), only screen and (min-width: 641px) and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-width: 641px) and (min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and (min-width: 641px) and (min-resolution: 2dppx)';
Foundation.Interchange.SPECIAL_QUERIES['largeretina'] = 'only screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), only screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (min-resolution: 2dppx)';
Foundation.Interchange.SPECIAL_QUERIES['xlargeretina'] = 'only screen and (min-width: 1921px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-width: 1921px) and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-width: 1921px) and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), only screen and (min-width: 1921px) and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-width: 1921px) and (min-resolution: 192dpi), only screen and (min-width: 1921px) and (min-resolution: 2dppx)';
```

- I've made sure that the above is loaded before `$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });` in `application.js`.
- I've tried loading the plugin using the regular HTML `<img>` tag but I can't seem to point the `data-interchange` attribute to the correct asset path.

```html
<img data-interchange=
     "[assets/headorbit/smallnormal.jpg, small], 
      [assets/headorbit/mediumnormal.jpg, medium], 
      [assets/headorbit/largenormal.jpg, large],
      [assets/headorbit/smallretina.jpg, smallretina], 
      [assets/headorbit/mediumretina.jpg, mediumretina], 
      [assets/headorbit/largeretina.jpg, largeretina]">
```

- I've tried replacing `[assets/headorbit/*.png]` with all the possible path combinations I could think of. Also, I've placed the `headorbit` folder in the public folder but I can't seem to point to that location either. Also, for some reason, the `push` to Heroku fails when the images are located in the public folder.
- Because of the failure to point to the correct path using regular HTML I've tried to use Rails helpers. First I've tried using `image_tag` but it  translates into `<img src="">` in HTML, and in Foundation's code snippet for adding Interchange to a image there is no `src` attribute, it's just `<img data-interchange[..]`. When using `image_tag(""...)` helper, if I leave the `src:""` empty, the image still doesn't load, and if I pass a path to a image, as in `image_tag(headorbit/smallnormal.png)` the interchange doesn't work, but the image I point to gets loaded, but when I inspect the page source I notice that Rails' Asset Pipeline adds a random number to my file name:

```html
<img src="/assets/headorbit/smallnormal-6bf4b83c1c324add60d876a1072d16a55c7279809611674bdac9b5064f2156e7.png" alt="Space">
```

I've come to learn that this is called fingerprinting and I have no idea how to disable it only for images.

I suspected that the Interchange plugin was getting messed up buy the fingerprint applied on each image by Rails' pipeline, but after passing each `asset_path` an `skip_pipeline: true` it still didn't work, and I can't get to load any image.

- After some research I found out I could span the `<img>` tag in HTML (without `src`) using `tag('img')` in Rails, so I've tried that too, thinking that the `src` was causing the problem, but that didn't work either.

Back to the drawing board, and after two days and hundreds of opened tabs I gave up and decided to ask here for help in a last desperate attempt.

At the time of this post, my code looks like this:

```html
<%= tag('img',
         alt: "Imagine Header", 
         class: "orbit-image head-orbit-image",
         data: { interchange:
           "[#{asset_path("/assets/headorbit/smallnormal.png")}, (small)], 
            [#{asset_path("/assets/headorbit/mediumnormal.png")}, (medium)], 
            [#{asset_path("/assets/headorbit/largenormal.png")}, (large)], 
            [#{asset_path("/assets/headorbit/smallretina.png")}, (smallretina)], 
            [#{asset_path("/assets/headorbit/mediumretina.png")}, (mediumretina)], 
            [#{asset_path("/assets/headorbit/largeretina.png")}, (largeretina)]" }) %>
```

Also, I've tried various combinations of paths with `path_to_image` or `image_path` instead of `asset_path`, with no luck.

I'll stop here because I think my browser is going to crash, it's already lagging 5 seconds for a keystroke.

Thank you and I'm sorry for the rather long post.

Comment: It's slightly unclear what part of it doesn't work exactly. Does it work in development but not in production? Is the assets digest not being applied or something like that?

Comment: In general the method is `asset_path('headorbit/smallnormal.png')`, notice that you don't specify `assets`, as that is implied. You can also, and perhaps should, use `image_path` instead, just to make the intent clearer.

Comment: The digest is being applied and I suspect that this may be the reason why Foundation's Interchange plugin does not load the images anymore, although I tried passing `skip_pipeline: true` after each asset path, resulting in images without fingerprints, and it still didn't work.